# heroku push install error

Tags: heroku, plugins, installation, push

when I use command

```
heroku plugins:install http://github.com/ddollar/heroku-push
```

I can't install and An error occurred

```
 (node:9472) [MODULE_NOT_FOUND] @oclif/plugin-legacy: Plugin push: Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\rukid\AppData\Local\heroku\node_modules\push\index.js'
C:\Users\rukid\AppData\Local\heroku\node_modules\push
(node:9472) SyntaxError Plugin: heroku: C:\Users\rukid\AppData\Local\heroku\config.json: Unexpected string in JSON at position 72
module: @oclif/config@1.6.33
task: runHook prerun
plugin: heroku
root: C:\Program Files\heroku\client
See more details with DEBUG=*
Installing plugin http://github.com/ddollar/heroku-push... !
Error: no name in C:/Users/rukid/AppData/Local/heroku/package.json
    at Plugin.load (C:/Program Files/heroku/client/node_modules/@oclif/config/lib/plugin.js:33:19)
```

Error : no name in ~
        at Plugin.load ~ 
what's problem?

Answer (score 0):

that plugin will not work with the latest Heroku CLI